# PDO - get the result of a COUNT(*)?

Tags: php, pdo

During the new user registration process, I'm trying to find whether a user name or a user email are already in the db.  To do that, I want to find the number of rows where the identifier (email or user name) matches records in the database.  If I don't screw up, the only possible return values are 0 or 1.  My function is below, but I need help to complete it.

```
function checkUserExists($userIdentifier, $tableColName){
 $dbConnection=$this->dbInstance->createConnexion();
 $query=$dbConnection->prepare("SELECT count(*) FROM users WHERE ".$tableColName."= :userIdentifier");
 $query->bindParam(":userIdentifier", $userIdentifier);
 $result=$query->execute();
 if( ????? >0){
  $return false;
 } else return true;
}
```

Silly of me, I'm not sure how to get that count number.  I suppose it's some variation of `$query->fetch()`, but that's going to be an array right?

Comment: what does `$result` return? I thought this would already be your required value. Otherwise you might want to look into the PHP documentation http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php in particular `fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0)`

Comment: @moontear: [`execute`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) returns a boolean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`->fetchColumn(0)`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php) to get the 1 and only column from the next (one and only) rowset.

```
if ( $query->fetchColumn(0) > 0 ){
  return false;
} else return true;
```

Answer (score 7):

(Note: I haven't tested this, nor do I have PHP installed on my work machine to test it; I work in a C#/Java shop)

Likely, you'd want [`$query->fetchColumn();`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php)

You can also pass which column number you want, but it defaults to column 0.